# Jenkins - How to determine compatible promoted-builds plugin version?

Tags: jenkins, promoted-builds

We are using Jenkins ver. 2.19.1 and we want to add the promoted-builds plugin, but the latest version ([3.2](https://plugins.jenkins.io/promoted-builds)) needs some other plugins to be updated first.

Long story short - we can not update plugins - we can add new ones if they don't interfere with the old ones.

We fail to find a "by version" plugin dependency list for promoted-builds.

How can we find out which of [these](https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/promoted-builds/) available versions may be a good fit for our current jenkins/installed plugins versions?